# IPython %run magic not working unless directed to location

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've searched and read many a thread on this, but didn't find one quite like my issue.

When I use %run, or run I get the following error.

```
Error:
In [3]: run msq
ERROR:root:File `'msq.py'` not found.
```

I've added every folder to my PYTHONPATH that I have py files in.

Running Python 3.6.6 and IPython 6.5.0. on Windows 10.

The only way I can get it to work is to tell IPython where to look using Change Directory:

```
In [4]: cd C:\Users\mando\Documents\Python Scripts
C:\Users\mando\Documents\Python Scripts

In [5]: ls *.py
Volume in drive C is Windows
Volume Serial Number is B035-A99D

Directory of C:\Users\mando\Documents\Python Scripts

08/13/2018  05:36 PM               124 msq.py
08/13/2018  04:01 PM               124 mysquare.py
           2 File(s)            248 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  859,171,188,736 bytes free

In [6]: run msq
1 squared is 1
2 squared is 4
3 squared is 9
```

Same thing happens in Jupyter Notebook.

Is this how %run is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question. Yes, this is the expected behavior of `%run`. PYTHONPATH is used for `import` statements only Alternatively, if you don't want to `cd` to the correct dir, you could specify the full path to the file.